# Solution to Fibonacci Recursion Equations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, recursion

Let the sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq0}$ of the fibonacci numbers: $a_0 = a_1 = 1, a_{n+2} = a_{n+1} + a_n, n \geq 0$

Show that:

i) $$a^2_n - a_{n+1}a_{n-1} = (-1)^n \text{ for }n\geq1$$ 
I try to show this with induction:

$n=1:$ 
            \begin{align*}
    a^2_1 - a_{2}a_{0}&=1 - a_2a_0\\
    &= 1- (a_1 + a_0 )a_0\\
    &= 1-(1+1)1 = -1 = (-1)^1\\
   \end{align*}
Assume that: $a^2_n - a_{n+1}a_{n-1} = (-1)^n ,\forall n\geq1$

Inductive step:
            \begin{align*}
    a^2_{n+1} - a_{n+2}a_{n}
    &=(a_n + a_{n-1}) ^2 - (a_{n+1}+a_{n})(a_{n-1}-a_{n-2})\\ 
    &=a^2_{n}+2a_na_{n-1}+a^2_{n-1}-a_{n+1}a_{n-1}+a_{n+1}a_{n-2}-a_{n}a_{n-1}+a_{n}a_{n-2}\\
    &=(a^2_{n}-a_{n+1}a_{n-1})+(a^2_{n-1}-a_{n}a_{n-1})+2a_na_{n-1}+a_{n+1}a_{n-2}+a_{n}a_{n-2}\\
    &=\underbrace{(-1)^n + (-1)^{n-1}}_{=0}+2a_na_{n-1}+a_{n+1}a_{n-2}+a_{n}a_{n-2}\\
    &=2a_na_{n-1}+a_{n+1}a_{n-2}+a_{n}a_{n-2}\\
    &=??\\
   \end{align*}

ii) $$\sum \limits_{i=0}^na_i=a_{n+2}-1 , n\geq0$$

iii) $$a^2_{n-1}+a^2_n=a_{2n} \text{ and } a_{n-1}a_n+a_na_{n+1}=a_{2n+1}, n\geq1$$

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 2):

Another flavor on the inductive step argument:
$$
\begin{split}
a_n^2-a_{n+1}a_{n-1}
      &= a_n^2-(a_n + a_{n-1})a_{n-1} \\
      &= a_n^2 - a_n a_{n-1} - a_{n-1}^2 \\
      &= a_n(a_n-a_{n-1}) - a_{n-1}^2 \\
      &= a_n a_{n-2} - a_{n-1}^2 \\
      &= -\left( a_{n-1}^2 - a_n a_{n-2}\right),
\end{split}
$$
reducing to the inductive hypothesis...

Answer (score 1):

Since the first term of the induction process for part one has been established the t remains to be seen for general $n$. Now,
\begin{align}
a_{n+1}^{2} - a_{n} \, a_{n+2} &= a_{n+1}^{2} - a_{n} \, ( a_{n+1} + a_{n} )\\
&= a_{n+1} ( a_{n+1} - a_{n} ) - a_{n}^{2} \\
&= a_{n-1} \, a_{n+1} - a_{n}^{2} = (-1)^{n+1}.
\end{align}
This provides $a_{n}^{2} - a_{n-1} \, a_{n+1} = (-1)^{n}$.

For the second part:
Using $a_{n} = a_{n+2} - a_{n+1}$ then 
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_{i} &= \sum_{i=0}^{n} ( a_{i+2} - a_{i+1} ) = a_{n+2} - a_{1}.
\end{align}

For the third part:
Using the solution of the difference equation in the form $(\alpha - \beta) a_{n} = \alpha^{n} - \beta^{n}$ where $2 \alpha = 1 + \sqrt{5}$ and $2 \beta = 1 - \sqrt{5}$. Now,
\begin{align}
a_{n}^{2} + a_{n-1}^{2} &= \frac{1}{5} \left[ (\alpha^{2n} - 2(-1)^{n} + \beta^{2n}) + (\alpha^{2n-2} + 2 (-1)^{n} + \beta^{2n-2}) \right] = a_{2n-1}. 
\end{align}

For the fourth part:
\begin{align}
a_{n} ( a_{n+1} + a_{n-1} ) &= \frac{a_{n}}{\alpha - \beta} \, \left[ \alpha^{n} \left( \alpha + \frac{1}{\alpha} \right) - \beta^{n} \left( \beta + \frac{1}{\beta} \right) \right] \\
&= \frac{(\alpha^{n} - \beta^{n})(\alpha^{n} + \beta^{n})}{\alpha - \beta} \\
&= a_{2n}.
\end{align}

Comment: thank you for your effort. For part three i want to show that $a^2_n+a^2_{n-1}=a_{2n}$ and not $=a_{2n-1}$

Comment: @Noah  It will take some effort to show your formula $F_{n}^{2} + F_{n-1}^{2} = F_{2n}$ where $F_{n}$ are the Fibonacci numbers.